# Double left join in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I wonder if there is a better way to do that. I know how to get the end results in multiple steps.

I have 2 tables that have car info in a SQL Server database.

The first looks like this and is stored in our database

Table Name: `Ours`

```
Dealer  RegID   Feature       Included 
--------------------------------------
CarsRus 312904  A41:Insured   1
CarsRus 292965  A41:Insured   1
CarsRus 146278  A41:Insured   0
CarsRus 660838  A41:Insured   0
CarsRus 216326  A41:Insured   1

ChpCars 312904  A41:Insured   0
ChpCars 292965  A41:Insured   1
ChpCars 146278  A41:Insured   1
ChpCars 660838  A41:Insured   0
ChpCars 216326  A41:Insured   0

AutoMob 312904  A41:Insured   0
AutoMob 292965  A41:Insured   1
AutoMob 146278  A41:Insured   1
AutoMob 660838  A41:Insured   1
AutoMob 216326  A41:Insured   0

CarsRus 312904  M38:Serviced   0
CarsRus 292965  M38:Serviced   0
CarsRus 146278  M38:Serviced   0
CarsRus 660838  M38:Serviced   0
CarsRus 216326  M38:Serviced   1

ChpCars 312904  M38:Serviced   1
ChpCars 292965  M38:Serviced   0
ChpCars 146278  M38:Serviced   1
ChpCars 660838  M38:Serviced   1
ChpCars 216326  M38:Serviced   0

AutoMob 312904  M38:Serviced   1
AutoMob 292965  M38:Serviced   1
AutoMob 146278  M38:Serviced   1
AutoMob 660838  M38:Serviced   0
AutoMob 216326  M38:Serviced   1


CarsRus 312904  Y77:Cleaned   1
CarsRus 292965  Y77:Cleaned   0
CarsRus 146278  Y77:Cleaned   0
CarsRus 660838  Y77:Cleaned   1
CarsRus 216326  Y77:Cleaned   0

ChpCars 312904  Y77:Cleaned   0
ChpCars 292965  Y77:Cleaned   1
ChpCars 146278  Y77:Cleaned   1
ChpCars 660838  Y77:Cleaned   1
ChpCars 216326  Y77:Cleaned   0

AutoMob 312904  Y77:Cleaned   0
AutoMob 292965  Y77:Cleaned   0
AutoMob 146278  Y77:Cleaned   1
AutoMob 660838  Y77:Cleaned   1
AutoMob 216326  Y77:Cleaned   0
```

The 2nd table we got from a partner and looks like this:

Table Name: `Partner`

```
RegID   Feature       Included
------------------------------
312904  A41:Insured   1
292965  A41:Insured   0
146278  A41:Insured   1
660838  A41:Insured   1
216326  A41:Insured   0

312904  M38:Serviced   0
292965  M38:Serviced   1
146278  M38:Serviced   0
660838  M38:Serviced   1
216326  M38:Serviced   0

312904  Y77:Cleaned   1
292965  Y77:Cleaned   0
146278  Y77:Cleaned   0
660838  Y77:Cleaned   1
216326  Y77:Cleaned   0
```

In the 2nd table there is no `Dealer` column as there is only one `Dealer` (the partner).

What I want to do is to identify the difference between the included features both tables.

So the output would be something like this:

```
Dealer  RegID   Feature       Ours  Partner
-------------------------------------------
CarsRus 292965  A41:Insured   1     0
CarsRus 146278  A41:Insured   0     1
CarsRus 660838  A41:Insured   0     1
CarsRus 216326  A41:Insured   1     0

ChpCars 312904  A41:Insured   0     1
ChpCars 292965  A41:Insured   1     0
ChpCars 660838  A41:Insured   0     1


AutoMob 312904  A41:Insured   0      1
AutoMob 292965  A41:Insured   1      0

CarsRus 292965  M38:Serviced   0      1
CarsRus 660838  M38:Serviced   0      1
CarsRus 216326  M38:Serviced   1      0

ChpCars 312904  M38:Serviced   1   0
ChpCars 292965  M38:Serviced   0   1
ChpCars 146278  M38:Serviced   1   0

AutoMob 312904  M38:Serviced   1   0
AutoMob 146278  M38:Serviced   1   0
AutoMob 660838  M38:Serviced   0   1
AutoMob 216326  M38:Serviced   1   0

ChpCars 312904  Y77:Cleaned   0   1
ChpCars 292965  Y77:Cleaned   1   0
ChpCars 146278  Y77:Cleaned   1   0

AutoMob 312904  Y77:Cleaned   0   1
AutoMob 146278  Y77:Cleaned   1   0
```

I can do that using a temp table that looks like this

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
              (
                  Dealer varchar(50), 
                  RegID bigint, 
                  Feature varchar(50), 
                  Ours int, 
                  Partner int
              )
```

Then table `Ours` is left joined to `Partner` where partner `RegID` is null then insert into the temp table; and again `Partner` left join `Ours` and update the temp table

But this process is not the best way.

Can I build this in a single query?

Comment: Please show us your current query. Sounds like you wanted a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Please explain how you want to compare the tables. If a query joins all rows where the RegID is equal and the Feature is equal and the Included is different, is this already the result you are looking for? Or do you also want to include missing rows in table 1 and/or 2? Or is it still something else you want the query to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a query like this:

```
select
  o.Dealer, o.RegID, o.Feature, o.Included as 'Ours', p.Included as 'Partner'
from ours o
  left join partner p on o.RegID = p.RegID and o.Feature = p.Feature
where
  o.Included != p.Included;
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a3819/9)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I used Squirrel's advice and used FULL OUTER JOIN and did the job

```
SELECT *, 
FROM OURS O full outer join Partner P on O.Feature = P.Feature and O.RegID = P.RegID
where O.Included <> P.Included
order by O.Dealer
```